# Resign First Responder

Tags: swift

I was wondering how I could get rid of my search bar whenever I switch to my detailView, so I don't have to keep pressing cancel on the Search Bar whenever I switch to the detailView.

Here is my detailView Code.

```
import UIKit

class DetailViewLemon: UIViewController {

var sentData1:String!


@IBOutlet weak var DetailCarMake: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var Zacks: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var TheStreet: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var MarketWatch: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var StockMaster: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var Nasdaq: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var InvestorPlace: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var Benzinga: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var Rating: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    DetailCarMake.text = sentData1


    self.title = sentData1


    if self.title == "Apple" {


        Zacks.text = "Zacks Rank: Buy"

        TheStreet.text = "The Street: Buy"

        MarketWatch.text = "MarketWatch: Buy"

        StockMaster.text = "StockMaster: Buy"

        Nasdaq.text = "Nasdaq Rating: Buy"

        InvestorPlace.text = "InvestorPlace Rating: Buy"

        Benzinga.text = "Benzinga Rating: Buy"

        Rating.text = "Buy"
    }

    if self.title == "Google" {


        Zacks.text = "Goog Zacks Rank: Buy"

        TheStreet.text = "Goog The Street: Buy"

        MarketWatch.text = "MarketWatch: Buy"

        StockMaster.text = "StockMaster: Hold"

        Nasdaq.text = "Nasdaq Rating: Buy"

        InvestorPlace.text = "InvestorPlace Rating: Hold"

        Benzinga.text = "Benzinga Rating: Buy"

        Rating.text = "Buy"
    }






}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `prepareForSegue` of your `TableViewController` you should call `self.searchController.searchBar.resignFirstResponder()` (replacing names of variables with whatever they actually are, as you didn't show that code.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use "view.endEditing(true)" in your viewWillDisappear

```
func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
     super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
     view.endEditing(true)
}
```

It closes keyboard regardless of whichever input is being FirstResponder